# Simple 1 vs 1 Fight Simulation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a simple program that defines two imaginary fighters with only a name and amount of health.

Right now this is what I have written:

```
import random

def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

hpRed = 20
hpBlu = 20

def attack():
    damage = random.randrange(1,3)

    return hpRed - damage
    return hpBlue - damage

def fighterRed(name, hpRed):
    print(str(name) + " has " + str(hpRed) + " health left.")

def fighterBlue(name, hpBlu):
    print(str(name) + " has " + str(hpBlu) + " health left.")

def battle():
    fighterRed("Branden",hpRed)
    fighterBlue("Alex",hpBlu)

    while ((hpRed > 0) and (hpBlu > 0) is True):
        attack()

    else:
        print("The battle is over!")

        if (hpRed > 0):
            return "Red Player is victorious!"
        else:
            return "Blue Player is victorious!"

battle()
```

So far I constantly receive the error "hpRed referenced before assignment". What can I change to get it to properly pass on the value of hpRed and hpBlu?

Comment: While the code you posted has a number of problems, it will not cause the UnboundLocal exception you mention. Next time, post your _actual_ code and the full traceback of the error message.

Answer (score 3):

There were a couple of errors:

- You were using two different names: `hpBlue` and `hpBlu`
- You were returning two values instead of changing the values of the variables you defined.
- Your printing functions were just executing 1 time. (Added inside the `while` so it prints each iteration)

**Code:**

```
import random

hpRed = 20
hpBlu = 20

def attack():
    global hpRed, hpBlu
    damage = random.randrange(1,3)
    hpRed = hpRed - damage
    hpBlu = hpBlu - damage

def fighterRed(name, hpRed):
    print(str(name) + " has " + str(hpRed) + " health left.")

def fighterBlue(name, hpBlu):
    print(str(name) + " has " + str(hpBlu) + " health left.")

def battle():   

    while (((hpRed > 0) and (hpBlu > 0)) is True):
        fighterRed("Branden",hpRed)
        fighterBlue("Alex",hpBlu)
        attack()

    else:
        print("The battle is over!")

        if (hpRed > 0):
            return "Red Player is victorious!"
        else:
            return "Blue Player is victorious!"

battle()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually making any changes to either player's hp; look at your attack() function and start checking your variables.

Answer (score 0):

The `hpRed` and `hpBlue` (which is misspelled in at least one place by the way) variables are defined at the module ("global") level. The names inside the functions are function-local names, which cannot see global variables unless they are explicitly assigned to globals. That would look like this:

```
def attack():
    global hpRed, hpBlue
    # rest of your function
```

While you *could* do this simply with globals, it's not very good practice. I recommend passing the value into any functions that need it, or putting it in a class so that methods of the class can operate on it.

```
def attack(hpr, hpb):
    # calculate damage, then...
    return (hpr - damage, hpb - damage)
```

You may notice that I changed your `return` statement. What you'd written wouldn't work the way you wanted it to: once you `return`, you can't `return` again from the same method call (that behavior would be more like a `generator`). If you want to return both the new red HP and the new blue HP, return a tuple containing them both.

This code has some other problems as well-- you're never actually changing the global variables, for instance, and you'll save yourself some headache if you put a `print` call inside the `while` loop so you can see how the hp changes.